# How do I retrieve a CSLA property's friendly name from outside the class?

Tags: c#, csla

The property looks like this:

```
private static PropertyInfo<bool> FooProperty=
        RegisterProperty<bool>(c => c.Foo, "Foo Friendly Name");
public bool Foo
{
    get { return GetProperty(FooProperty); }
    private set { SetProperty(FooProperty, value); }
}
```

I would like to recieve "Foo Friendly Name" from outside the class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loosen the access on your static `FooProperty`:

```
//access FooProperty from inside the assembly where it is defined
internal static PropertyInfo<bool> FooProperty=
    RegisterProperty<bool>(c => c.Foo, "Foo Friendly Name");
```

or

```
//access FooProperty from anywhere
public static PropertyInfo<bool> FooProperty=
    RegisterProperty<bool>(c => c.Foo, "Foo Friendly Name");
```

Then access it from outside its class:

```
string fooName = FooClass.FooProperty.Name;
```